# Constructing multidimensional array

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a problem for an online bootcamp. I can't seem to figure out how to pass a multidimensional array  into the constructor. I've looked around on here for a solution but I can't seem to find anything ruby specific to initializing a multidimensional array. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

[Problem]

Build a class that allows us to build a new image with the data we specify. Make it possible for the class to output the image to the screen. Your goal is to have the following code work:

```
image = Image.new([
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0]])
image.output_image
```

And when you run that code it will output the following to the terminal window:

```
0000
0100
0001
0000
```

Here is what I have written.

```
class Image 
  def initialize
    @image= Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) }
  end 

  def output_image 
    @image.each do |x|
      x.each do |y|
        puts y 
      end 
    end 
  end

end 


image = Image.new([
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0]        
])
image.output_image
```

I'm getting the error:

```
app.js:2:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Your error message does not match your code. 1. `app.js` is a pretty odd name for a Ruby file; 2. Your `initialize` method does not take any arguments, but the error message indicates that it expects two arguments. Are you sure that the error message in your question is the error message raise by the exact code in your question, or is it the error message from a different version of your code that you haven't shared with us?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `initialize` method doesn't take any arguments. You can't pass an argument to a method that doesn't take any arguments.

Change this:

```
def initialize
  @image = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) }
end
```

To this:

```
def initialize(image)
  @image = image
end
```

Comment: ...and replace `@image.each` loop with `@image.each do |x|; puts x.join; end`.

Comment: Jordan, You're edits worked perfectly! I think when I was posting I copied and pasted into an app.js file. None the less, I ran the code in the js file and it was working fine. wierd. Cary, thank you, I was puzzled on how to get the output of the loop to print in 4s ex 0000.... put the x.join made it work. Just curoius In java this year we would use something like this. 'code' def output_image 
      @image.each do |x|
        x.each do |y|
        
          String row += y 
          end
        puts row 
        end 
      end

Comment: @CarySwoveland `puts @images.map(&:join)`

Comment: @meagar, I can't see the forest for the trees.